# S3 Delete files inside a prefix folder using boto3, How to keep the prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I try to delete files from a prefix with a boto3 loop, but I found the prefix was delete as well because the last loop will return the prefix as the Key.
How to keep the prefix folder? Thanks

```
s3client = boto3.client('s3')

for object in s3client.list_objects_v2(Bucket = 'bucket_filedrop', Prefix = 'key_daily')['Contents']:
                file_delete = object['Key']
                
                s3client.delete_object(Bucket = 'bucket_filedrop', Key = file_delete)
```

Answer (score 0):

If a folder was created by the **Create Folder** function in the Amazon S3 management console, then it creates a zero-length object with the same name as the folder.

Therefore, you code could do this:

```py
  if object.size > 0:
    s3client.delete_object(Bucket = 'bucket_filedrop', Key = file_delete)
```

FYI: Please note that it is not necessary to create folders or prefixes. Objects can be created in *any* path, without needing to first create directories. The directories will magically 'appear' when the object is created and will then 'disappear' when all objects are removed from the path. So, there might be little reason fro creating or keeping the folder.

Comment: Great solution,Thanks